# how to compile ios app using react native >= 0.73.5 , bugsnagreactnative >= 0.72.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, bugsnag

I get this error "this file must be compiled as obj-C++.

If I downgrade to react-native 0.73.4, seems to work. I'm using the new React Native Architecture.

How do make latest versions of react native and bugsnagreactnative work together?

[image]